# Suppose that f and g are bounded functions, prove whether or not $3f - 4g$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

Do the same rules as adding bounded functions apply? My attempt is pitiful to put it nicely.

I'm aware there exists constants such that:

$M \geq |f(x)|$

$N \geq |g(x)|$

$M + N \geq |f(x)| + |g(x)|$

but here I'm subtracting, so the equality $N\geq|g(x)|$ gets changed to $-N \leq -|g(x)|$.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: $|a-b|\leq|a|+|b|$.  And $|-x|=|x|$.  These two facts should get you there

Comment: $-M\le f(x)\le M$, $-N\le g(x)\le N\Longrightarrow -N\le -g(x)\le N$, and $3f - 4g\le 3M + 4N$, $3f - 4g\ge -3M - 4N$; or $|3f - 4g|\le 3M + 4N$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$|3f(x)|\le 3M$ and $|4 g(x)| \le 4N$. Now use : $ |A-B|=|A+(-B)| \le |A| + |(-B)|=|A|+|B|$ (triangle inequality)

Comment: Obviously ! there was a stupid typo. I edit, tank yoou :)

Answer (score 1):

you can get the result by using another form of the triangle equation (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Triangle_inequality), which is $|a-b| \leq |a| + |b|$. You could derive this by setting $\tilde{b} = -b$ and then: $|a-b| = |a+\tilde{b}| \leq |a| + |\tilde{b}| = |a| + |-b| = |a| + |b|$, where I used the triangle inequality you already know.
This gives:
$$
|f(x)| \leq M \forall x \, \, \in \mathbb{R} \\
|g(x)| \leq N \forall x \, \, \in \mathbb{R} \\
|3f(x) - 4g(x)| \leq |3f(x)| + |4g(x)| = 3|f(x)| + 4|g(x)| \leq 3M+4N \, \, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
Here I used $|a*b| = |a|*|b|$.

I hope this answer did help you solve your problem.

Lukas

Comment: Seems I was a bit too slow.